# Why AVR-GCC compiler throws an error when overloading with the same variables but as PROGMEM?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, avr-gcc, progmem

My question is more like: Why the compiler *"thinks"* that a *"PROGMEM variable"* is the same as a *"plain Variable"*? is it because [PROGMEM-keyword is *"just"* a macro](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html) and nothing more? or is it for some other reason too? **and is there any workaround..?**

#### ISSUE demonstration:

Lets consider the below example:

```cpp
class object {
public:
  object(int* variable);
  object(int* variable PROGMEM);
};
```

it throws `error: 'object::object(int*)' cannot be overloaded` as if it is the same.

```
sketch_jul31a:4:3: error: 'object::object(int*)' cannot be overloaded

   object(int* variable PROGMEM)

   ^~~~~~

sketch_jul31a:3:3: error: with 'object::object(int*)'

   object(int* variable)

   ^~~~~~

exit status 1
'object::object(int*)' cannot be overloaded
```

#### Outro:

I came across this issue a while ago when i was developing a library, I've asked about it on  the arduino-forum but i had not any answer and so i've thought after a long period to ask about it once again, here.

Comment: That annotation doesn't make sense for a function parameter that's a plain value. Overloading on pointer to progmem versus pointer to data memory would make some sense, but that would have to be part of the type of the pointer - can't remember if there's an annotation for that.

Comment: PROGMEM is information for the linker where to store the variable. it has nothing to do with the variable type.

Comment: @Mat my fault on this, i forgot the * before posting it lol

Comment: @Juraj that's quite sad.. and it's what i was expecting as an answer actually...

Comment: **I was hoping for a workaround though...**

Comment: there it is in the second answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect the compiler to treat linker sections as type qualifiers, but you can define an overload for a `const int*`, which is pretty close to the semantics of PROGMEM (a ROM location).

I wonder what you plan on doing with a `const int*` though. All you will ever be able to do is read it, so it's basically equivalent to a plain constant `int` value, with the added cost of two bytes of ROM.

Comment: **That's a great one!** it makes sense for something like ```const int* variable PROGMEM``` since PROGMEM, is constant anyways. That was just a "silly" example of mine, in my case [i had to store a banch of weights and biases](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/NeuralNetworks/blob/e3f0db1d173d2dd03e32aebbaf9d14c71941bf99/src/NeuralNetwork.h#L350) *(for readonly purposes if PROGMEM)*, but at the end i got away with MACROS..

Comment: I see. Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

`__attribute__((progmem))` is a compiler feature, not a C++ language feature, so it does not participate in the overload resolution. The both `object(int variable);` and `object(int variable PROGMEM);` looks like the double declaration of `object(int variable);` in terms of C++.